# pop/remove items out of a python tuple

Tags: python, tuples

I am not sure if I can make myself clear but will try.

I have a tuple in python which I go through as follows (see code below). While going through it, I maintain a counter (let's call it 'n') and 'pop' items that meet a certain condition.

Now of course once I pop the first item, the numbering all goes wrong, how can I do what I want to do more elegantly while removing only certain entries of a tuple on the fly?

```
for x in tupleX:
  n=0
  if (condition):
     tupleX.pop(n)
  n=n+1
```

Comment: `tuple`s are immutable, and don't have a `pop` method.  Are you really talking about a `list`?

Comment: @DSM was correct 6 years ago, but Python 3 allows slicing on tuples, so one can effectively pop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok I figured out a crude way of doing it.

I store the "n" value in the for loop when condition is satisfied in a list (lets call it delList) then do the following:

```
    for ii in sorted(delList, reverse=True):
    tupleX.pop(ii)
```

Any other suggestions are welcome too.

Answer (score 83):

As `DSM` mentions, `tuple`'s are immutable, but even for lists, a more elegant solution is to use `filter`:

```
tupleX = filter(str.isdigit, tupleX)
```

or, if `condition` is not a function, use a comprehension:

```
tupleX = [x for x in tupleX if x > 5]
```

if you really need tupleX to be a tuple, use a generator expression and pass that to `tuple`:

```
tupleX = tuple(x for x in tupleX if condition)
```

Comment: For others' reference, the generator expression is optimal in terms of speed.

Comment: @Alecg_O: can you provide benchmarks for that claim?  In fact, in the case that the `condition` is an (unapplied) C function (as in the example I provided), `filter` is usually faster; generator expressions must execute some python bytecode, but aren't required to create a call-frame (also as in my example for the list comprehension).

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter), the filter and generator solutions are functionally identical - both return an iterable of the original filtered by condition, and by this definition both are constant time. However, assuming the OP requires a tuple for output, the difference comes in the conversion back. For proof: take tuple() off the generator and they'll both return instantly, but tuple() the filter and it takes longer proportional to the size of tupleX.

Comment: Interesting sidenote: I came across this post while looking for the most efficient way to "remove" a single item from a tuple. While these are all great solutions, ironically "x = list(x); x.remove(<item>); x = tuple(x)" is faster than any of them :P

Answer (score 19):

Yes we can do it.
First convert the tuple into an list, then delete the element in the list after that again convert back into tuple.

Demo:

```
my_tuple = (10, 20, 30, 40, 50)

# converting the tuple to the list
my_list = list(my_tuple)
print my_list  # output: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

# Here i wanna delete second element "20"
my_list.pop(1) # output: [10, 30, 40, 50]
# As you aware that pop(1) indicates second position

# Here i wanna remove the element "50"
my_list.remove(50) # output: [10, 30, 40]

# again converting the my_list back to my_tuple
my_tuple = tuple(my_list)


print my_tuple # output: (10, 30, 40)
```

Thanks

Comment: It's a terrible method. You will allocate a list, perform an action and then allocate another tuple. Way faster and elegant would be to create a new tuple without the element

Answer (score 8):

In **Python 3** this is no longer an issue, and you really don't want to use list comprehension, coercion, filters, functions or lambdas for something like this.

Just use

```
popped = unpopped[:-1]
```

Remember that it's an immutable, so you will have to reassign the value if you want it to change

```
my_tuple = my_tuple[:-1]
```

Example

```
>>> foo= 3,5,2,4,78,2,1
>>> foo
(3, 5, 2, 4, 78, 2, 1)
foo[:-1]
(3, 5, 2, 4, 78, 2)
```

If you want to have the popped value,,

```
>>> foo= 3,5,2,4,78,2,1
>>> foo
(3, 5, 2, 4, 78, 2, 1)
>>> foo, bit = foo[:-1], foo[-1]
>>> bit
1
>>> foo
(3, 5, 2, 4, 78, 2)
```

Or, to work with each value of a tuple starting at the back...

```
foo = 3,5,2,4,78,2,1
for f in reversed(foo):
    print(f)  # 1; 2; 78; ...
```

Or, with the count...

```
foo = 3,5,2,4,78,2,1
for f, i in enumerate(reversed(foo)):
    print(i, f)  # 0 1; 1 2; 2 78; ...
```

Or, to coerce into a list..

```
bar = [*foo]
#or 
bar = list(foo)
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you want dictionaries?

```
d = dict( (i,value) for i,value in enumerate(tple))
while d:
    bla bla bla
    del b[x]
```

Comment: no I have to work with a tuple as its given to me by an external function that I can't edit-old hierarchical code with too many dependancies.

Comment: thank you, I will try this -more elegant than my method.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple but practical solution.

As DSM said, tuples are immutable, but we know Lists are mutable.
So if you change a tuple to a list, it will be mutable. Then you can delete the items by the condition, then after changing the type to a tuple again. That’s it.

Please look at the codes below:

```
tuplex = list(tuplex)
for x in tuplex:
  if (condition):
     tuplex.pop(tuplex.index(x))
tuplex = tuple(tuplex)
print(tuplex)
```

For example, the following procedure will delete all even numbers from a given tuple.

```
tuplex = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
tuplex = list(tuplex)
for x in tuplex:
  if (x % 2 == 0):
     tuplex.pop(tuplex.index(x))
tuplex = tuple(tuplex)
print(tuplex)
```

if you test the type of the last tuplex, you will find it is a tuple.

Finally, if you want to define an index counter as you did (i.e., n), you should initialize it before the loop, not in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

A shorter way perhaps:

```
tup = (0, 1, 2, 3)
new_tup = (*tup[:-2], tup[-1])
print(new_tup) # (0, 1, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is the tuple applied to a list comprehension, but to extract one
item this could work:

```
def pop_tuple(tuple, n):
    return tuple[:n]+tuple[n+1:], tuple[n]
```

Answer (score 0):

say you have a `dict` with tuples as keys, e.g:  `labels = {(1,2,0): 'label_1'}` you can modify the elements of the tuple keys as follows:

```
formatted_labels = {(elem[0],elem[1]):labels[elem] for elem in labels}
```

Here, we ignore the last elements.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to convert to **set** and bring back to tuple

```
tupleX = (
    "ZAR",
    "PAL",
    "SEV",
    "ALC",
    "LPA",
    "TFN",)

remove = (
    "LPA",
    "TFN",)

tuple(set(tupleX) - set(remove))
```

('ZAR', 'PAL', 'ALC', 'SEV')