# How do you remove a user's input from a list?

Tags: python

I am working on this code and I cannot get the "removeLetter" to delete the letter the user chooses from the "chosen" list. I figured out I can't use list functions with strings, but I don't know how to go about making the 
start.remove() code to work without converting the user's string input to match the item he/she would like to be removed from the "chosen" list. Can someone help me please?

```
import random

oneList = "a ", "b ", "c "
twoList = "d ", "e ", "f "
threeList = "g ", "h ", "i "
fourList = "j ", "k ", "l "

# Selects a letter at random from each list
oneRandom = random.choice(oneList)
twoRandom = random.choice(twoList)
threeRandom = random.choice(threeList)
fourRandom = random.choice(fourList)

# Displays chosen letter from each list
print("These are your letters.")
chosen = oneRandom + twoRandom + threeRandom + fourRandom
print(chosen)

# First user input
start  = input("Would you like to remove a letter? y or n? ")

# If start = yes then do this.
if start == 'y':
    removeLetter = input("What letter would you like to remove? ")

    # Removes user's chosen letter.
    keptLetters = chosen.remove(removeLetter)

    # Displays kept letters.
    print(keptLetters)
```

Comment: You might be getting tripped up because `oneList` through `fourList` aren't lists, they're tuples. Importantly, lists can be mutated (for example, items can be removed from them), and tuples can't.

Comment: lists are surrounded by `[]`, try running `type()` and you will see what @Kevin is saying

Comment: Also, instead of doing `start.remove`, you probably want to slice out from `chosen` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few issues in your code. I took the liberty to make it more pythonic for you.

## Python 2

```
import random

letter_sets = (("a", "b", "c"),
               ("d", "e", "f"),
               ("g", "h", "i"),
               ("j", "k", "l"))

# Selects a letter at random from each list
chosen = map(random.choice, letter_sets)

# Displays chosen letter from each list
print "These are your letters."
print " ".join(chosen)

# First user input
start = raw_input("Would you like to remove a letter? y or n?")

# If start = yes then do this.
if start[0].lower() == 'y':
    while(len(chosen) == 4): #Keep looping until a letter is chosen
        removeLetter = raw_input("What letter would you like to remove?")
        try:
            # Removes user's chosen letter.
            chosen.remove(removeLetter)
            # Displays kept letters.
            print " ".join(chosen)
        except ValueError: #If removeLetter is not in chosen
            print removeLetter, "is not in the list of letters"
```

## Python 3

```
import random

letter_sets = (("a", "b", "c"),
               ("d", "e", "f"),
               ("g", "h", "i"),
               ("j", "k", "l"))

# Selects a letter at random from each list
chosen = list(map(random.choice, letter_sets))

# Displays chosen letter from each list
print("These are your letters.")
print(" ".join(chosen))

# First user input
start = input("Would you like to remove a letter? y or n?")

# If start = yes then do this.
if start[0].lower() == 'y':
    while(len(chosen) == 4): #Keep looping until a letter is chosen
        removeLetter = input("What letter would you like to remove?")
        try:
            # Removes user's chosen letter.
            chosen.remove(removeLetter)
            # Displays kept letters.
            print(" ".join(chosen))
        except ValueError: #If removeLetter is not in chosen
            print(removeLetter, "is not in the list of letters")
```

1. Having multiple lists, and repeating your code is not very pythonic. So I've made the "lists" as a tuple of tuples (since you may not plan on modifying this). If so, then change to lists by denoting them with square brackets `[]` instead of parentheses `()`.
2. Since you're performing the same operation on multiple lists, you can use the [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function to get the results from all of them into a list.
3. `chosen` should remain a list, instead of a string, since you'll be manipulating it in the future by removing a letter.
4. You can easily [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) all the items in a list together as a string separated by a single space `" "`.
5. Since [`list.remove()`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) can send back a `ValueError` if the value isn't in the list, you'll want to handle that in a [`try..except`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/errors.html) block.
6. Can surround your logic with a [`while`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#while) loop to keep asking for a letter to remove if the previous attempts failed.
7. `chosen.remove` changes the original array, so you don't need to save it into `keptLetters`.

I hope this helps you out!

**Edit:** Added equivalent Python 2 code

Comment: I appreciate this and think I understand what you are saying. However, I get this error with your code. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\lettersTwo.py", line 25, in <module>
    removeLetter = input("What letter would you like to remove?")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'b' is not defined

Comment: Are you *sure* you copied the code correctly? I assume you're running Python 3. I made a [repl](https://repl.it/repls/BiodegradableSpryConference) for this.

Comment: Alright, I am sorry. I was actually running Python 2. I don't know why I still have it. I do have 3 installed though. Your program worked thank you!

Comment: @NickAndrulewicz, I updated my answer for Python 2. `map` result is a bit different, and `input` does as well. You can see in this [repl](https://repl.it/repls/WorseScholarlyIntercept). Please accept the answer if you feel like it has helped!

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your code specifically in this line:

```
keptLetters = start.remove (removeLetter)
```

You are calling the variable `start` but the variable `chosen` is the one with the list of letters. So this should work:

```
keptLetters = chosen.remove (removeLetter)
```

Comment: There's more issues than that. Especially since `chosen` is a string.

Comment: @Anderson Although that was a valid error you pointed out along with, I am still having trouble. I should've realized that I am also using tuples like others have said .Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21682804/pop-remove-items-out-of-a-python-tuple

Answer (score -1):

Je pense que sa  doit être ça

```
import random oneList = "a ", "b ", "c "
twoList = "d ", "e ", "f " 
threeList = "g ", "h ", "i " 
fourList = "j ", "k ", "l " 
# Selects a letter at random from each list 
oneRandom = random.choice(oneList) 
twoRandom = random.choice(twoList) 
threeRandom = random.choice(threeList) 
fourRandom = random.choice(fourList) 
# Displays chosen letter from each list 
print("These are your letters.") chosen = oneRandom + twoRandom + threeRandom + fourRandom print(chosen) 
# First user input 
start = input("Would you like to remove a letter? y or n? ") 
# If start = yes then do this. 
if start == 'y': removeLetter = input("What letter would you like to remove? ") 
# Removes user's chosen letter. 
keptLetters = chosen.remove(removeLetter)
# Displays kept letters. 
print(keptLetters)
```