# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'pop'

Tags: python-3.x

When writing list inside tuple, getting error:

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'pop'

```
fruits=('apple','banana', ['kiwi','grapes'])
fruits[1].pop()
fruits[1].append('rice')
print(fruits)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am getting:

> `str` object has no attribute `pop`

which is what I was expecting since `fruits[1]` is `'banana'` which is a string and strings do not have a `pop` method.

If you look at the next line you will run into a similar issue since strings also don't have an `append` method.

If you remove both of those lines you shouldn't have any errors with just the `list` inside of the `tuple`.

```
fruits = ('apple','banana', ['kiwi','grapes'])
print(fruits)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is coming from you trying to pop a string, in the second line of your code - not from adding a list in the tuple. Now as tuples are immutable in python, you will need to convert it into a list if you wish to start modyfing what is inside of it. A simple example using your code is below.

```
fruits=('apple','banana', ['kiwi','grapes'])
fruits_list = list(fruits)
fruits_list.pop(1)
fruits_list.insert(1, 'rice')
fruits = tuple(fruits_list)
print(fruits)
```

You can read more about it here: [pop/remove items out of a python tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21682804/pop-remove-items-out-of-a-python-tuple)